# Should it be possible to accept an answer on an on-hold question?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, accepted-answer

I just noticed an answer I wrote to a question before it was put on hold:

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/39647/14401

was accepted.  That seems odd.

Should it be possible to accept an answer on an on-hold question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this behavior is intentional.

> The asker of a closed question may still accept an answer.

Quoted from the answer on [What is a "closed" or “on hold” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question).

Comment: This is definitely useful if the question is eventually reopened. I suppose it could also be useful in helping get the question reopened - sometimes people inexplicably will accept answers while ignoring requests for clarification, and the check mark can help make it clear what they were looking for.